# Meta / Super / Windows keys not working

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 23.04

I have seen many questions asked here on AskUbuntu, SuperUser, and Reddit where people are having trouble getting their `Meta / Super / Windows` keys to work. I have tried all the suggestions but nothing is working. I don't know if this is an Ubuntu thing, a Gnome thing, an Gnome extension thing, or something with my Keyboard.

If I got to `Settings > Keyboard > Input Sources > English (US) Ellipses > View Keyboard Layout` a digital keyboard pops up. This window shows me that when I press either `Meta / Super / Windows` keys left or right, and the `Menu` key nothing happens.

I just turned off all of my Gnome Extensions so I don't think they are the problem. Some suggest going into `Gnome Tweaks > Keyboard & Mouse > Additional Layout Options` and changing the Alt and Win behavior. I have tried all of them. But as I previously stated my keys are not being registered.

Most answers suggest hitting `FN + {F1-12}` But I don't have an `FN` key and pressing the `F` key they suggest also does nothing. I have pressed all `F` keys then my `Meta / Super / Windows` keys and nothing changes.

Is there any other way to enable these keys? I have a Logitech G613 if that makes any difference.... I took my brother-n-laws keyboard works on my computer. Plugged my keyboard into my laptop doesn't work. So I Googled Logitech G613 and remembered....

#### OS info

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that my keyboard has a gaming mode. And part of gaming mode is disabling your windows keys so that they don't interrupt gaming....

[image]